# rsync: Delete extraneous files and dirs in dest

Tags: linux, rsync

I have two directories in `/test`:

```
$ ls /test/
dir1  dir2
```

I run:

```
$ rsync --recursive --links --perms --executability --times --delete /dir2 /test/
```

My expectation is that `/test/dir1` gets deleted, but it doesn't. Is there any way to make that happen? None of the `--delete*` options of rsync seem to do the job.

Thanks and best regards,
Martin

Comment: Logical : `rsync a b/` is a short way to type `rsync a b/a` then b/* excepted b/a is ignored. If you want `test` to be cleaned, you should prepare a source directory which contains only `dir2` and use `rsync -r --delete source test` without the `/` after test.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer The trailing `/` on the destination is irrelevant. It's on the source path it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have no `/` at the end of the source path (`/dir2`), you are instructing `rsync` to sync `/dir2` with `/test/dir2`.  With `--delete` added, `rsync` would remove all things under `/test/dir2` that do not exist in `/dir2`.

At no point is `/test/dir1` accessed or considered.

However, if you use `/dir2/` as the source path, `rsync` would sync `/dir2` with `/test` (not `/test/dir2`).  Adding `--delete` would delete both `/test/dir2` and `/test/dir1` as neither `/dir2/dir1` nor `/dir2/dir2` presumably exists.

The trailing `/` on the destination path is irrelevant, but the trailing `/` on the source path decides whether the source directory should be synced as a separate directory under the destination path (without `/`), or whether `rsync` should sync it to the destination path itself (with `/`).